# Select columns with multiple purcahses in a given date

Tags: sql, postgresql

[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeC5H.png)

I need to get names (FIO) of all the people that purchased product a and product b in any given day (but must be 2 purchases in a day) in april, or any other specified month.
What I tried to do is

```
with
    purchased_items as
        (
          select customer_key
          from purchase p
          join product pr
          on p.product_key = pr.product_key
          where pr.name in ('Teddy bear', 'LEGO') 
            AND p.date_sold BETWEEN '01.04.2019' AND '30.04.2019'
          group by customer_key
          having count(distinct p.product_key) = 2
        )
select *
from customer c
where exists (
      select *
      from purchased_items pui
      where c.customer_key = pui.customer_key
    );
```

But that only gives clients that bought 2 items in a month (not a single day).
I also suspect that it can be done by querying for `Date, Client_name (FIO), array_agg(product.Name /*group by date */ )` , but I am not sure how to implemet it.

Thank you in advance for any help !

EDIT: figured it out.

```
with a as (
SELECT c.FIO, p.date_sold, pr.Name
FROM customer c
JOIN purchase p ON c.customer_key = p.customer_key
JOIN product pr ON p.product_key = pr.product_key
Where p.date_sold BETWEEN  '01.04.2019' AND '30.04.2019' and (pr.name like '%LEGO%' OR pr.name like '%Teddy bear%') ),

count_name as (
select fio, count(distinct Name) as count, date_sold 
from a
group by date_sold, fio)

select DISTINCT FIO
from count_name
where count=2
```

Although it's probably very subotimal